# Can't create bucket without authentication

Tags: authentication, couchbase

We updated our Couchbase from 4.6 Community edition to 5.0.0-2873 Enterprise Edition for testing purposes and our software using the java-client started throwing InvalidPasswordException when trying to open a bucket.

As I've found, every newly created bucket has authType='sasl' and a randomly generated saslPassword.
I've tried creating a bucket using the CLI instead of the GUI:

```
couchbase-cli bucket-create -c localhost:8091 -u Administrator -p password --bucket=general --bucket-ramsize=1300 --bucket-type=couchbase --bucket-password=
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: unrecognized arguments: --bucket-password=password
```

I also tried the bucket-edit function with the same result.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/cli/cbcli/bucket-edit.html) the argument should be valid.

I also tried using the REST API to change bucket authentication (and similarly password), but even though this didn't throw any erros, the authType and the password remained the same.

```
curl -X POST -u Administrator:password -d 'authType=none' http://<host>:8091/pools/default/buckets/general
```

Again, according to the [documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/rest-api/rest-bucket-auth.html) this should work.

If I query the bucket information for the sasl password and provide that for the openBucket function then the connection works, however we really don't want to use this feature in our system.

So, any other ideas how it would be possible to remove the bucket authentication in our 5.0EE Couchbase setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Couchbase 5.0 we no longer support bucket passwords and have moved to using role based access control when connecting to buckets. This means that in 5.0 the standard (pre-production) way to connect to a bucket is by using the Administrator user and password that you created when setting up the cluster. In case you're unsure what the Administrator user is, it is the user you create when you first go through the Couchbase setup wizard or the it is the username and password you specify on the command line when running the couchbase-cli cluster-init command.

One thing to note is that using the Administrator user/password is the standard pre-production workflow. I would recommend that when you go into production you create separate users for your application which only have access to cluster resources they need to access in the cluster. You can do this by going to the Users tab in the Administration Console and creating a new user and giving them the Full Bucket Access role which is the standard role that applications should have.

You might now be saying to yourself that this all sounds great, but when I use the Administrator user/password I still am having issues. If this is the case the reason is because you have Couchbase 5.0, but your SDK is not new enough to handle the new RBAC authentication mechanism in 5.0. The workaround for this is to create a user in the Users tab with the same name as the bucket and give that user the Full Bucket Access role. You can then use this user to authenticate.

One last thing to mention is that during an upgrade from a pre-5.0 cluster to a 5.0 cluster Couchbase will automatically create a user for each bucket. The each user will have the same name as one of the buckets and the password for that user will correspond to the bucket password. This is done mainly to ensure that there is no application downtime during an upgrade. After upgrading the cluster the next step should ideally be to upgrade the Couchbase client library to have it start using RBAC authentication.

Comment: And I guess there is no proper workaround if you have multiple buckets configured? I can think of a messy workaround which is creating a user per bucket, named after the bucket. :-|

Comment: The workaround would be to create a user with the same name as each bucket like you mentioned. I'd recommend however that you update to the latest version of the SDK that you are using and take advantage of RBAC as soon as possible. Also, note that if you upgrade from pre-5.0 to 5.0 the users are created automatically. This workaround would only be needed if you really want to use the older SDK's with Couchbase 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stay with old approach and no password you can use cochbase-cli with --rbac-username and --rbac-password "", but you need to specify password as "", e.g.

```
./couchbase-cli user-manage -c localhost:8091 -u Admin -p password --set --rbac-username <UserForBucket> --roles bucket_full_access[<BucketName>] --rbac-password "" --auth-domain local
```